# Problems with Button in custom ViewCell

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Button in a ViewCell...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="ConnectionCrew.UI.Shared.Appointments.CompletionFormMain">
    <ViewCell.View>
        <Grid Margin="8, 16, 8, 16">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#bdbdbd" Padding="1">
                <Editor x:Name="txtBxShiftNotes" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="100" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="btnSubmit" VerticalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Confirm Attendence" BackgroundColor="Lime" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="50" />
        </Grid>
    </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Two undesirable things are happening.

1) The bottom of the containing ViewCell is just beneath the button's text - it's as if the baseline of the text is aligned to the bottom of the cell.

2) If I click on the button, its click event doesn't fire and the whole cell flashes. Except if I click just above the text - in which case there is no flashing and the click event is raised.

How can I fix these issues? I'd prefer no flashing, correct alignment and proper hit testing.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the margins to the child elements...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="ConnectionCrew.UI.Shared.Appointments.CompletionFormMain">
    <ViewCell.View>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Margin="8, 8, 8, 0" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="#bdbdbd" Padding="1">
                <Editor x:Name="txtBxShiftNotes" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="100" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Button Margin="8, 0, 8, 8" x:Name="btnSubmit" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="Confirm Attendence" BackgroundColor="Lime" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="50" />
        </Grid>
    </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your problem, but I suggest to:

1. Add "ColumnDefinition" property to your Grid ([Rows_and_Columns](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/#Rows_and_Columns))
2. Add `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` property to `StackLayout` control
3. Remove `Grid.Row` property from Editor control (it's inside a StackLayout, so StackLayout should have Row and Column property)
4. Add `Grid.Column` property to `Button` control
5. Post images of your actual problems
6. Do you have the problem on iOS, Android, UWP?
7. A repo on GitHub could be useful

Comment: Screenshot added. You can see how the button's text is aligned to the bottom of the cell. If I drag up, then you can see the row separator running across the button.

Comment: Grid.Row="0" seems to be the default so it makes no difference.